# Python: BeautifulSoup UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, text-files

I am trying to remove the HTML tags from some documents in a .txt format. However, there seems to be an error with the bs4 as far as I understand. The error that I am getting is the following:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Google Drive1/Thesis stuff/Python/database/get_missing_10ks.py", line 13, in <module>
    text = BeautifulSoup(file_read, "html.parser")
  File "C:\Users\Adrian PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 282, in __init__
    self._feed()
  File "C:\Users\Adrian PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\__init__.py", line 343, in _feed
    self.builder.feed(self.markup)
  File "C:\Users\Adrian PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\bs4\builder\_htmlparser.py", line 247, in feed
    parser.feed(markup)
  File "C:\Users\Adrian PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\html\parser.py", line 111, in feed
    self.goahead(0)
  File "C:\Users\Adrian PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\html\parser.py", line 179, in goahead
    k = self.parse_html_declaration(i)
  File "C:\Users\Adrian PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\html\parser.py", line 264, in parse_html_declaration
    return self.parse_marked_section(i)
  File "C:\Users\Adrian PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\_markupbase.py", line 160, in parse_marked_section
    if not match:
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'match' referenced before assignment
```

And the code that I am using is the following:

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path_to_10k = "D:/10ks/list_missing_10k/"

path_to_saved_10k = "D:/10ks/list_missing_10kp/"

list_txt = os.listdir(path_to_10k)

for name in list_txt:
    file = open(path_to_10k + name, "r+", encoding="utf-8")
    file_read = file.read()
    text = BeautifulSoup(file_read, "html.parser")
    text = text.get_text("\n")
    file2 = open(path_to_saved_10k + name, "w+", encoding="utf-8")
    file2.write(str(text))
    file2.close()
    file.close()
```

The thing is that I have used this method on 51320 documents and it worked just fine, however, there are a few documents which it cannot do. When I open those HTML documents they seem the same to me.. If anyone could have any indication of what could be the problem and how to fix it it would be great. Thank you!

**EXAMPLE OF FILE: https://files.fm/u/2s45uafp**

Comment: Looks like a bug. It might be worth narrowing it down to the repeatable test case (capture whatever data it is that causes this error) and raise on github.

Comment: Huh, if I'm not mistaken it looks like a python bug. I'll have a look at the source code shortly.

Comment: [It is](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_markupbase.py#L160)! But I don't know what `self.error('unknown status keyword %r in marked section' % rawdata[i+3:j])` is and why it lets the execution continue

Comment: @roganjosh Thank you for taking the time to look into it... do you a have a suggestion for what I could use instead?

Comment: No, not currently. This is a bug in CPython that needs fixing but I've not raised issues on the bug tracker before so I want to be sure of the circumstances that cause it. I've raised it on chat; nice catch :)

Comment: Could you provide an example file where this breaks?

Comment: @AndrasDeak  Yes. I uploaded a file where this breaks at: https://files.fm/u/2s45uafp

Comment: What version of Python is this? I can't recreate in 3.6.2 so we're narrowing down on what change causes this bug

Comment: The newest version of cpython on github is buggy, but it should raise a different error due to the bug... weird.

Comment: @roganjosh I am running python 3.7.1 x64

Comment: We've hit a bit of a dead-end for now in working this out. Hopefully someone else will be able to add some insight later in the day. Your code _should_ throw an error, but not the one you're seeing.

Comment: I'm curious: on your system does `def error` raise `NotImplemented` in `"C:\Users\Adrian PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\_markupbase.py"` and is `def error(...)` anywhere in `"C:\Users\Adrian PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\html\parser.py"`. The answer _should_ be "yes, no".

Comment: @AndrasDeak in parser.py there is no method called error

Comment: @Adrian can you put it in a pastebin please?

Comment: @AndrasDeak This the pastebin link: https://pastebin.com/UPDf6kbT

Comment: Sorry, we need to see the pastebin of `_markupbase`

Comment: Here is the  _markupbase: https://pastebin.com/i0t2GzMV

Comment: Try to isolate the file which produce the error, and iteratively delete parts of the file to find which line is causing the error.

Comment: Could you include a sample of the problem in the post? I've tried accessing the links but neither showes the file any longer.

Comment: Looks similar to https://bugs.python.org/issue34480

Comment: @roganjosh this is arguably poor design on the part of the standard library (clients are supposed to implement a method such that it raises an exception), but it's BeautifulSoup that has the bug (its implementation does not do so).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/scrapy/w3lib
https://w3lib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
pip install w3lib
```

and

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
```

And then `remove_tags(data)`  return clear data.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution which is using regular expression for removing the HTML tags.

```
import re

TAG_RE = re.compile(r'<[^>]+>')

f = open("C:\Temp\Data.txt", "r")
strHtml=f.read()

def remove_Htmltags(text):
    return TAG_RE.sub('', text)

strClearText=remove_Htmltags(strHtml)
print(strClearText)
```